# How to share assets/resources/images between android projects

Tags: android, resources, android-assets, shared-directory

Let's say that I have 2 projects with that use the same images, stored in folder: /assets/pictures/

Is there a way I can share those images, without including them in both projects?

Comment: see SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Library Project, and place the drawables, assets, there (see [Managing Projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) in the Android documentation

Then reference this Library Project from your Application Projects.

Make sure you're using Gradle/Android Studio though. Ant doesn't support assets in Library Projects (or at least didn't -- this might've changed).